# Histogram with grades

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I need to make a histogram in Python with grades distribution. I use matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title('Histogram Grades')
data = [1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3]
data.sort
plt.hist(data)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

The histogram it's OK but I don't like the grouping python uses to show grades in x-axis. I wonder if there is a way (some hist parameter or another plot library), where I can have bars for each individual grade?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a little fussy, but you can customize almost everything once you have the right arguments. The main problems seem to be getting `bins` right and setting the base width with `rwidth`.

Maybe this is closer to what you are hoping for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title('Histogram Grades')
data = [1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 2]
plt.hist(data, rwidth=.8, bins=np.arange(min(data), max(data)+2) - 0.5)

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(data), max(data)+1, 1.0))
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want bar charts for the frequencies, I would personally recommend using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module to count the frequency. It returns a dictionary whose keys are the grades and the values are their corresponding frequencies. 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from collections import Counter

```
data = [1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 1, 3, 10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3]
freqs = Counter(data)
# Counter({1: 2, 3: 6, 10: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 5: 2, 7: 4})

plt.bar(freqs.keys(), freqs.values())
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Histogram Grades')
plt.show()
```

[image]